# Django: For a fixed len. model list relation, is it OK to use a fixed number of OneToOneField's in a parent model rather than a FK in the child model?

Tags: python, django, database-design

I am designing a week-based menu application.  I am wondering if I should just do this:

```
class MenuWeek(models.Model):
    sunday = OneToOneField("MenuDay")
    monday = OneToOneField("MenuDay")
    #etc through Saturday

class MenuDay(models.Model):
    # some stuff here, but not a foreign key to MenuWeek
```

instead of this:

```
class MenuDay(models.Model):
    week = ForeignKey("MenuWeek") # (with no OneToOne's defined in MenuWeek)
```

Is the first way a good way to implement a short "fixed-length" list relationship between parent and child or should i just stick with ForeignKey in the MenuDay and enforcing length through forms validation?   I'm thinking the administration may be cleaner, the first way, where its clear which day of a week you are editing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would never use your first option. You'll end up repeating yourself all over the place to run a particular section of code for each weekday. The second option will result in much nicer code down the road.

Comment: I took your advice and found a way to enforce the fixed-length list (through clever use of the Django admin) while using the second method.  I actually tried it the first way just to see and was seeing exactly what you warned against.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, the second option is much better. But you can probably even get rid of `MenuWeek` and just add a date or week field in `MenuDay` and do the filtering this way, unless `MenuWeek` is supposed to hold some data.